# Go test function with pointer reference

Tags: go

I'm working on unit tests on a Go project, and I'm new to Go. So to start I wanted to test something easy. And I started with this function:

```
func (this *Service) InList(idPerson string, personsId []string) bool {
    for _, personsId := range personsId {
        if id == idPerson {
            return true
        }
    }

    return false
}
```

Service is a struct defined on top of the class.

This is the test I wrote:

```
func TestValidatePersonID(t *testing.T) {
   personID := "12345"

   personIDs := []string{"12345", "123456t", "1234567a"}

   ok := *Service.InList(personID, personIDs)

   if !ok {
      t.Errorf("Id %v not found", personID)
   }
}
```

If i try to Call Service without * I get the error:

> invalid method expresion (needs pointer reciever)

If i try to call the function (*Service).inList, it says I'm missing an argument. I'm new to Go if anyone could point to me what I'm doing wrong and how Could I get a pointer receiver of that Service in my test?. I would appreciatte it.

Comment: Well, as `InList` does not use the `*Service` you should not make it a method of Service at all: A plain function would do. And please: Do not name receivers `this`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to call a method on an *instance* of its receiver type. So, for a method defined on `*Service`, you must call it on an *instance of* `*Service`:

```
var foo *Service
foo = &Service{}
foo.InList(personID, personIDs)
```

However, in your case, there's no reason for this to be a method; it doesn't seem to have anything at all to do with its receiver (it never references it), so it could just be a regular function. Also note that it's unidiomatic to name the receiver `this` in Go.

I also highly recommend at least taking the [Go tour](https://tour.golang.org/methods/1), which covers writing methods in detail, with interactive examples.

Answer (score 3):

The correct syntax for the [method expression](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Method_expressions) is:

```
ok := (*Service).InList(nil, personID, personIDs)
```

This snippet adds `nil` as the receiver argument and uses parentheses to specify the type correctly.

The approached used in the question is not idiomatic. Either call a method on a value

```
s := Service{}
ok := s.InList(personID, personIDs)
```

or convert the method to a function.

Comment: While technically accurate, this is not a construct one sees very often in the wild. It's more common to call a method on an actual `nil` pointer than to call a method as a function like this.

Answer (score 1):

If you do not reference the receiver object, then you should not have one, keep your code as simple as possible.

There are three ways of writing a method or function, with each its own purpose.

1. without receiver, when no receiver is referenced in the function ( we call this a function )
2. a value receiver, the receiver is referenced, but not changed in the method ( we call this a method )
3. a pointer receiver, something in the receiver will be changed in the method